# python: how to make a pd dataframe header's second component the top row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (df) which looks like the following:

```
                               0        1        2      3       4   5
s4-e1-p1-cohex.wav             0.0      0.0      0.0    Male    No  0.0
s4-e1-p2-thev-buckle.wav       50000    0.51     98039  Male    Yes 1
s4-e10-p1rly-newlyweds.wav     0        0        0      Female  No  0
s4-e10-p2-ks-away.wav          150000   0.2      750000 Male    Yes 1
```

currently, this dataframe's header is the first two rows:

```
df.columns.values.tolist()
#[(0, 0.0), (1, 0.0), (2, 0.0), (3, 'Male'), (4, 'No'), (5, 0.0)]
```

I am wondering how I can move the second row in this printed out dataframe to the top row in the panda dataframe. In other words, the row printed below is not in the pd dataframe and I want to include that as the top row of the dataframe (**s4-e1-p1-cohex.wav is not in the column names nor in row names**):

```
s4-e1-p1-cohex.wav             0.0      0.0      0.0    Male    No  0.0
```

I have to tried to search around but did not find an answer to this weird formatting. I know I can just make the column names a different vector and insert it back to the dataframe but I am wondering if there are other ways that's less convoluted.

```
 df.to_dict() 

 {(0, 0.0): {'s4-e1-p2-thev-buckle.wav': 50000.0,
   's4-e10-p1rly-newlyweds.wav ': 0.0,
    's4-e10-p2-ks-away.wav': 150000.0},
  (1, 0.0): {'s4-e1-p2-thev-buckle.wav': 0.51,
  's4-e10-p1rly-newlyweds.wav': 0.0,
   's4-e10-p2-ks-away.wav': 0.2},
  (2, 0.0): {'s4-e1-p2-thev-buckle.wav': 98039.0,
  's4-e10-p1rly-newlyweds.wav': 0,
   's4-e10-p2-ks-away.wav': 750000 },
  (3, 'Male'): {'s4-e1-p2-thev-buckle.wav': 'Male',
  's4-e10-p1rly-newlyweds.wav': 'Female',
   's4-e10-p2-ks-away.wav': 'Male'},
  (4, 'No'): {'s4-e1-p2-thev-buckle.wav': 'Yes',
  's4-e10-p1rly-newlyweds.wav': 'No',
   's4-e10-p2-ks-away.wav': 'Yes'},
  (5, 0.0): {'s4-e1-p2-thev-buckle.wav': 1,
  's4-e10-p1rly-newlyweds.wav': 0,
   's4-e10-p2-ks-away.wav': 1},
```

Comment: How did you read in the DataFrame?

Comment: Add df.to_dict() to this question, so we can see exactly what the dataframe looks like.

Comment: added the df.to_dict()

Comment: This dataframe is converted from a dictionary but results in this weird format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess something is wrong with your `df` output in the question as I could not generate your output.  I did this

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = [(0, 0.0), (1, 0.0), (2, 0.0), (3, 'Male'), (4, 'No'), (5, 0.0)])

df.loc['s4-e1-p2-thev-buckle.wav']= [50000.0, 0.51, 98039, "Male", "Yes", 1]

df.loc['s4-e10-p1rly-newlyweds.wav']= [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, "Female", "No", 0]

df.loc['s4-e10-p2-ks-away.wav'] = [150000.0, 0.2, 750000, "Male", "Yes",1]
```

The output of `df.to_dict()` is

```
{(0, 0.0): {'s4-e1-p2-thev-buckle.wav': 50000.0, 's4-e10-p1rly-newlyweds.wav': 0.0, 's4-e10-p2-ks-away.wav': 150000.0},
 (1, 0.0): {'s4-e1-p2-thev-buckle.wav': 0.51, 's4-e10-p1rly-newlyweds.wav': 0.0, 's4-e10-p2-ks-away.wav': 0.2},
 (2, 0.0): {'s4-e1-p2-thev-buckle.wav': 98039, 's4-e10-p1rly-newlyweds.wav': 0.0, 's4-e10-p2-ks-away.wav': 750000},
 (3, 'Male'): {'s4-e1-p2-thev-buckle.wav': 'Male', 's4-e10-p1rly-newlyweds.wav': 'Female', 's4-e10-p2-ks-away.wav': 'Male'},
 (4, 'No'): {'s4-e1-p2-thev-buckle.wav': 'Yes', 's4-e10-p1rly-newlyweds.wav': 'No', 's4-e10-p2-ks-away.wav': 'Yes'},
 (5, 0.0): {'s4-e1-p2-thev-buckle.wav': 1, 's4-e10-p1rly-newlyweds.wav': 0, 's4-e10-p2-ks-away.wav': 1}}
```

My `df` output via Jupyter notebooks is

[image]

I really do not understand your question and your desired output. There is no way to remove the header from `df` output. Unless, you print it to a file and then use python to remove the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
df.drop(df.index[0])
```

to remove the first row.

Comment: I do mean that i want to remove the first row. What i want is converting the **s4-e1-p1-cohex.wav**  row to the first row of this dataframe. Currently, it is showing as the part of header and  **s4-e1-p1-cohex.wav**  does not belong to header or row name

Comment: Your question is not clear as you have read the data into `df`.

If it is a csv file, you can try to use `skiprows` argument in `pd.read_csv()`.

Comment: this is a dataframe I converted from a dictionary and resulted in this werid format